# What paper does Ron stick infront of a car's window that belongs to the people from IRS?

Tags: plot-explanation, dallas-buyers-club

There is a scene which Ron Woodroof's stuffs (medicines) are being taken by the IRS. He is very angry (And cocky) and he sticks a paper in front of a car's window that belongs to the people from IRS.  Can we guess that that what the paper is about?

Comment: The FDA (via the local police and DEA) were the ones that confiscated his drugs. The IRS took financial records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe in that scene, which is the IRS seizing financial records for an audit, the "paper" Ron grabs and slaps on the windshield of their car is his checkbook (or just one check).

From [the script](http://focusguilds2013.com/workspace/media/dbc_final-script_-12.02.12-.pdf):

> INT. DALLAS BUYERS CLUB MOTEL - RON'S OFFICE - DAY
>
> Ron and David Wayne look on as two IRS AGENTS carry out boxes of
> receipts and other financial records.
>
> RON: Nice work, fellas, great. This is how you got Al Capone, ain't
> it?
>
> *As the Agents exit:*
>
> DAVID WAYNE: Don’t piss them off. If there’s a fine, we'll pay it.
>
> RON: A fine? Fine, alright, how much? Ten thousand? Twenty thousand?
> I'll write you a check right now.
>
> *Ron grabs his check book.*
>
> RON: You think that will stop me, you motherfuckers!
>
> *David waves Ron down with his hands.*